# Trying to create an HtmlHelper to wrap a common pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the following code to create an HTMLHelper method called EditBlockFor that takes the model and creates the LabelFor and EditorFor in one pass instead of having to do both each time. Where I think I am passing the HtmlHelp properly when it comes time to get the HtmlString from helper.LabelFor I do not have the LableFor method available. What am I missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyTest.Code
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
     public static IHtmlString EditBlockFor<T>
     (
     this HtmlHelper<T> helper,
     Expression<System.Func<T, String>> prop,
     Dictionary<String, Object> htmlAttributes = null
     )
        {
            HtmlString label;
            HtmlString item;


            label = helper.LabelFor(prop, htmlAttributes);
            item = helper.EditorFor(prop, htmlAttributes);

            return new HtmlString(label+" "+item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot one Include

using System.Web.Mvc.Html;